# Word for "person who relies"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the term for **rely** as validator is for validate or reader is for read.

The closest term I found is **relying party** but I would prefer a single word.

Answer (score 3):

> Noun: **dependant**  di'pen-dunt
>
> A person who relies on another person for support (especially financial support)
>
> - dependent
>
> Sounds like: dense, dentst, dependen
>
> Derived forms: dependants
>
> Type of: receiver, recipient
>
> Encyclopedia: Dependant

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=dependant)

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary defines words that most established dictionaries have not picked up yet. So use with caution:

***Relier*** (plural *reliers*) -- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/relier)

> (noun) One who relies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adjective "reliable" if you trust someone. You would say you are "dependant" on your spouse's support or care to live. However, the sense of relying financially on someone is a bit different. It's very common to use the following terms to describe someone who relies on someone else financially by choice over necessity depending on the nature of the relationship:  User, kept, beneficiary, gigolo, trustee, enabled, keeper, enabler. It merely depends on what's being exchanged. I have never used or seen the word "relier" used anywhere by anyone who speaks English. Although 
found in the dictionary, its usage really isn't popular at all. Perhaps  Dictionaries aren't always as reliable as one may think? But really, has anyone ever used the word?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).